# ruby convert class name in string to actual class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I call a class from a string containing that class name inside of it?  (I guess I could do case/when but that seems ugly.)

The reason I ask is because I'm using the `acts_as_commentable` plugin, among others, and these store the commentable_type as a column.  I want to be able to call whatever particular commentable class to do a `find(commentable_id)` on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I think what you want is [`constantize`](http://apidock.com/rails/Inflector/constantize)

That's an RoR construct. I don't know if there's one for ruby core

Comment: perfect, that's just what I was looking for.

Comment: For plain Ruby, you'd use `Module.const_get`. The advantage of `constantize` is that it works even with deeply nested namespaces, so you could do `'Functional::Collections::LazyList'.constantize` and get the class LazyList from the module Collections in the module Functional, whereas with `const_get`, you'd have to do something like `'Functional::Collections::LazyList'.split('::').reduce(Module, :const_get)`.

Answer (score 52):

```
"Object".constantize # => Object
```

Comment: Please note that `.constantize` is a Rails method, you won't find it in plain Ruby

Answer (score 51):

## It depends on the string...

If it already has the proper shape (casing, pluralization, etc), and would otherwise map directly to an object, then:

Rails:

```
'User'.constantize # => User
```

Ruby:

```
Module.const_get 'User' # => User
```

But otherwise (note the difference in casing):

```
'user'.constantize # => NameError: wrong constant name user

Module.const_get 'user' # => NameError: wrong constant name user
```

Therefore, you must ask... is the source string singular or plural (does it reference a table or not?), is it multi-word and AlreadyCamelCased or is_it_underscored?

With Rails you have these tools at your disposal:

Use [camelize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize) to convert strings to UpperCamelCase strings, even handling underscores and forward slashes:

```
'object'.constantize # => NameError: wrong constant name object
'object'.camelize # => "Object"
'object'.camelize.constantize # => Object
'active_model/errors'.camelize # => "ActiveModel::Errors"
'active_model/errors'.camelize.constantize # => ActiveModel::Errors
```

Use [classify](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify) to convert a string, which may even be plural (i.e. perhaps it's a table reference), to create a class name (still a string), then call [constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) to try to find and return the class name constant (note that in Ruby [class names are constants](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/classes.html#UE)):

```
'users'.classify => "User" # a string
'users'.classify.constantize # => User

'user'.classify => "User" # a string
'user'.classify.constantize # => User

'ham_and_eggs'.classify # => "HamAndEgg"
```

In POR (Plain Old Ruby), you have [capitalize](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-capitalize), but it only works for the first word:

```
Module.const_get 'user'.capitalize => User
```

...otherwise you must use fundamental tools like strip, split, map, join, etc. to achieve the appropriate manipulation:

```
class HamAndEgg end # => nil
Module.const_get ' ham and eggs '.strip.gsub(/s$/,'').split(' ').map{|w| w.capitalize}.join # => HamAndEgg
```

Comment: You should use camelize instead of classify since classify is for table names and doesn't handle pluralization very well.

Comment: Your answer is really valuable, but you should use "titleize" for table name which includes by space, and remove white space from string to make meaning full class name.

Comment: @SSR yes, you could: `' ham and eggs '.titleize.gsub(/ /,'').constantize # => HamAndEggs`

Answer (score 25):

I know this is an old question but I just want to leave this note, it may be helpful for others.

In plain Ruby, [`Module.const_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Module.html#method-i-const_get) can find nested constants. For instance, having the following structure:

```
module MyModule
  module MySubmodule
    class MyModel
    end
  end
end
```

You can use it as follows:

```
Module.const_get("MyModule::MySubmodule::MyModel")
MyModule.const_get("MySubmodule")
MyModule::MySubmodule.const_get("MyModel")
```

Answer (score 7):

When ActiveSupport is available (e.g. in Rails): [`String#constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-constantize) or [`String#safe_constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-safe_constantize), that is `"ClassName".constantize`.

In pure Ruby: [`Module#const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get), typically `Object.const_get("ClassName")`.

In recent rubies, both work with constants nested in modules, like in `Object.const_get("Outer::Inner")`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to convert string to actuall class name to access model or any other class

```
str = "group class"

> str.camelize.constantize 'or'
> str.classify.constantize 'or'
> str.titleize.constantize

Example :
  def call_me(str)
    str.titleize.gsub(" ","").constantize.all
  end

Call method : call_me("group class")

Result:
  GroupClass Load (0.7ms) SELECT `group_classes`.* FROM `group_classes`
```