# Convert string to class name without using eval in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, class, eval

I have something like this:

```
string = "Post"
```

I would like to convert the string to a class name literal. I use eval like this to convert the string:

```
eval(string) #=> Post
```

Being a javaScript developer I try to avoid eval. Is there a better way of doing this in Ruby? Or is using eval the preferred way of handling this?

Comment: are you on rails on plain ruby?

Comment: Plain ruby. I am aware that Ruby on Rails has a method for this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464007/ruby-convert-class-name-in-string-to-actual-class

Comment: Possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464007/ruby-convert-class-name-in-string-to-actual-class/38149803#38149803

Comment: @EdgarOrtega not a duplicate. That question is for RoR. This question is for just Ruby.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try

```
class Post
end

Object.const_get("Post")
```

Which returns the `Post` class

Answer (score 26):

Use [Module.const_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get)

```
string = "Fixnum"
clazz = Object.const_get(string)
clazz.name # => "Fixnum"
```

If you are in a rails context, you can also use the `#constantize method on string

```
clazz = string.constantize # => Fixnum
```

Comment: constantize is best than others